# How can i change Terminal Settings to automatically close terminal after Execution using shell script

Tags: terminal, mac, macos, applescript

when i execute some command file or shell file after execution terminal remains open and its not look appropriate i want to close the terminal by script without changing settings manually in MAC
please help..

Comment: Have you tried using the Automator application?

Comment: nope, i dont know about automator application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit the terminal by calling to two commands after each other, execute script and then exit

```
$> myScript.sh && exit
```

Comment: With the default configuration for Terminal, adding `&& exit` after a command does not close Terminal.

Comment: @user3439894 What do you mean with "default configuration"? This works for me and I haven't changed anything special with my terminal except the look although I run OS X 10.14. I see you have tagged your question `applescript`, are you doing this from an applescript or directly in the terminal?

Comment: It doesn’t close Terminal for me either.  It closes the window or tab that was running the shell process, but the Terminal app doesn’t exit until I physically do it myself.  Therefore, @JoakimDanielson , I wonder if you have not noticed the app still running in the dock, or whether your indicator lights are off.

Comment: @CJK I am pretty sure the Terminal app was not quit for me either and that was not my interpretation of the question since closing a window and exiting an app are two very different things.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes I can see now how it has two possible interpretations, as "terminal" can refer to the interface with the shell, or the name of the macOS program that acts as a terminal.  But, I think your interpretation is more correct here, as I see the OP was attentive to which of  the two uses of "terminal" used a capitalised "T".  A pity, as I've been searching for a  way to quit _Terminal_ upon closing the last open terminal.  Moving along...